# RPC author_extrinsicUpdate, missing TxIndex

Tags: json-rpc, extrinsicstatus

Currently not sure if I missed something here, but I'm expecting `TxIndex` in the `inblock` and `finalized` updates of the extrinsic, but it seems to be missing.

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0""
"method": "author_extrinsicUpdate""
"params": {
  "subscription": "BThmgFpwWuKESjPy",
  "result": {
    "finalized": "0xa5276e980b57003a924c52adaf8ee6f3711228d085a63d1212c93648e5ae5dc5"
  }
}
```

In substrate, it has the value `TxIndex`, so I'm currently unsure, why it is not in, or if I gets lost in an underlying layer.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub enum TransactionStatus<Hash, BlockHash> {
    ...
    /// Transaction has been finalized by a finality-gadget, e.g GRANDPA.
    #[serde(with = "v1_compatible")]
    Finalized((BlockHash, TxIndex)),
    ...
}
```

Is it supposed to be in the **author_extrinsicUpdate**? If, not what would be the fastest way to get the information of the TxIndex?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I currently switched to use the new JSON-RPC which delivered the information [NEW JSON-RPC Specification](https://paritytech.github.io/json-rpc-interface-spec/api/transaction_unstable_submitAndWatch.html), it doesn't exactly answer the question, but it removes the need to know it.

Here is the answer for the block, of `TransactionEvent` in this case involving the `TxIndex`.

[image]